# ajax запрос не отправляет json объект для Kendo грида

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo

Есть кендо грид для которого в datasource прописан так transport

```
setDataSourceListGrid = function (obj) {

    var _grid = $("#MainGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedRow = $(obj).closest("tr");
    var selectedItem = _grid.dataItem(selectedRow);
    var Id = selectedItem.Id; // Этот Id отправляем на сервер

    dataSourceListGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "AwardHonorary/awardListGrid/",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: { id: Id },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Ошибка при чтении данных.");
                },
                complete: function (e) { }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        alowUnsort: true,
        schema:
         {
             data: function (data) {
                 return data.List || [];
            },  
             total: "Count",
             model: {
                 fields: {
                     "field1": { editable: false, type: "int" },
                     "field2": { editable: false, type: "int" },
                     "field3": { editable: false, type: "string" },
                     "field4": { editable: false, type: "string" },
                     "field5": { editable: false, type: "string" }   
                 }
             }

         }


    });

    return dataSourceListGrid;
}
```

Грид прописан так:

```
$("#awardContendersGrid").kendoGrid({

    pageable: {
        messages: {
            display: "{0} - {1} из {2} элементов",
            empty: "Список пуст",
            page: "Страница",
            of: "из {0}",
            itemsPerPage: "элементов на страницу",
            refresh: "Обновить"
        }
    },
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    columnMenu: false,
    dataSource: setDataSourceListGrid (obj),
    columns: [
        { field: "field1", title: "Поле1", type: "int", hidden: true },
        { field: "field2", title: "Поле2", type: "int", width: "30px" },
        { field: "field3", title: "Поле3", type: "string", width: "200px" },
        { field: "field4", title: "Поле4", type: "string", width: "150px" },
        { field: "field5", title: "Поле5", type: "string", width: "250px" },
      ]

  });
```

}

На сервере принимающий метод выглядит так:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Test(Int64 id, int take, int skip, int page, int pageSize, List<GridSort> sort = null)
    {
```

В фидлере ловит отправляемый аджаксом запрос и показывает следующее:

> id=1&take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=HomeAdress&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc

Т.е. видим что не происходит сериализации в json объект

При этом в сам метод на сервере переменные Int64 id, int take, int skip, int page, int pageSize приходят, а вот сортировка - нет. Знающие люди подскажите, чего не хватает?

P.S. Настройка serverSorting: true для кендо грида включена

Comment: Куска жса,который вы приложили, не достаточно, что бы помочь решить вам проблему.

Comment: Мстислав, что ещё требуется?

Comment: В идеале развертка вашего кода в телериковском доджо

Comment: Мстислав, дополнил описание в вопросе

Comment: Вы хотели добавить сортировку?

Comment: да, чтобы сортировка приходила с метод на сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не правильный метод контроллера, он должен выглядеть так:

```
public DataSourceResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    IQueriable myQ ...;         
    // Тут происходит кендо-магия. В `request` содержатся всякие клиентские параметры, типа сортировок, пейджинг, фильтрация и прочее.
    return myQ.ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

Comment: но Id же параметр в request не попадёт?

Comment: Если вам нужно передать доп. параметр, то просто добавьте после `request` параметр `int id`. Параметр нужно передавать путем указания его в урле в виде `&id=123`

Comment: Мстислав, а можно обойтись как-то без DataSourceResult? У меня этого класса нет в проекте, а добавлять что-то не очень желательно. В любом случае, спасибо Вам большое за помощь!)

Comment: @Дмитрий это стандартный класс для `KendoUI` как и метод `.ToDataSourceResult`. Если у вас их нету в проекте, то это значит, что вы не подключили библиотеки от KendoUI к проекту, что я вам настоятельно рекомендую сделать, раз вы работаете с кендо из C#

Comment: ясно. Ещё раз спасибо Мстислав!